# Make ionic ion-item have a transparent background

Tags: css, ionic2

Is there a way to make the background of an ionic 2 `<ion-item>` be transparent?

I have tried this CSS but it doesn't make the item transparent:

```
.list .item, .item-content .item-inner .item-block .item-ios
{
  background: transparent !important;
}
```

**ADDED CODE**

My HTML looks like this:

```html
<ion-content class="pu-my-plans-background">

  <div *ngIf="hasPlans">
    <ion-list no-lines class="pu-item-list">
      <!--<ion-item-group reorder="true" (ionItemReorder)="reorderItems($event)">-->
        <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let plan of plans; let i = index" >
          <ion-item class="pu-section-list-item pu-my-plans-item" (click)="editPlan(plan.id, plan.rev, plan.title, i)">
            {{ plan.title }}
            <br>
            <span class="pu-my-plans-plan-date">{{ plan.updated}}</span>
            <button *ngIf="plan.important" ion-button clear item-right>
              <ion-icon name="ios-alert-outline"></ion-icon>
            </button>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item-options side="right">
            <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="deletePlan(plan.id, plan.rev)">
              <ion-icon name="delete"></ion-icon>
              Delete
            </button>
          </ion-item-options>
        </ion-item-sliding>
      <!--</ion-item-group>-->
    </ion-list>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

And my CSS  like this:

```css
page-my-plans {

}

.pu-my-plans-plus-circle {
  display: block;
  //border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: $pu-orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 38px;
  width: 38px;
}

.pu-my-plans-plus-circle span {
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 8.5px;
}
.pu-plan-addButton {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 14px;
  margin-top:-2px;
}


.pu-section-list-item{
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  font-weight:$pu-item-font-weight;
  font-size:$pu-item-font-size;
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-right:0px;
}
.item{
  background: transparent !important
}
// THEMING CSS
// ===========
//
.pu-my-plans-background {
  background-image: url("../assets/img/my_plan_bg@2x.png");
  background-size: cover !important;
}
.pu-my-plans-item {
  border-style:solid;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-color: $pu-orange;
}
.pu-my-plans-plan-date {
  color: $pu-orange;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

I have tried every combination of styling the ionic 2 items as I can think of but the best I can get with this is to get a white background behind the ion-item. The ion-content has an image background but I can't get to see this through the ion-item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the ionic 2 item sliding background color you can change the main sass variable

```
 $item-ios-sliding-content-background(transprent);
 $item-md-sliding-content-background(transprent);
```

In your src -> theme -> variables.scss file

you can find all the variables [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/)

Answer (score 11):

Here  is a solution in Ionic 4:

**HTML:**

```
<ion-list class="bg-transparent">
    <ion-item color="none" lines="none">
        Some random text
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item color="none" lines="none">
        Some random text
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bg-transparent {
  background: transparent;
}
```

**Important things to note:**

- Set background color of the main list to transparent by applying the class and adding CSS as shown.
- Add the `color="none"` attribute to each of the ion-item.
- `lines="none"` remove the lines under each of the ion-item

That should do it!

Comment: this is the solution for ionic 4+

Comment: Well done! Also works for **Ionic 6** :)

Answer (score 8):

For Android

```
.item-md {
  background: transparent;
}
```

For iOS

```
.item-ios {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this in **Ionic 5**  using CSS Custom Properties.

For `ion-item`

```css
ion-item {
    --ion-item-background: transparent;
}
```

For `ion-list`

```css
ion-list {
    --ion-item-background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Working exactly in ionic-5. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`<ion-item color="transparent">
 </ion-item>`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Answer (score 0):

You are using sliding item. Try using the below code

```
.pu-item-list ion-item-sliding{
  background: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: That gives me a white background. The <ion-content> has a background image which is not seen with the css you give. I don't know how to create a plunker for ionic 2

Comment: if you want to override ionic 2's styles you can avoid !important but wrapping your sass in .md,.ios{}

Comment: @gerdi, I have used important so that i can use my own class name and it is not necessary for me to define for all the platforms using .md, .ios

Comment: sass wrapped in .md,.ios take priority over ionic2 styles, its not about custom class names, if you are styling over an ionic 2 component, those styles will take priority. Its hardcore adding !important in your styles. With sass it is almost never needed

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
ion-item {
    --ion-item-background: transparent;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

ion-list {
    --ion-item-background: transparent;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a new variable in variable.scss like this:

```
--ion-color-transparent: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
```

and use it like this:

```
<ion-item  color="transparent" padding="0px"><ion-input type="email" placeholder="username"></ion-input></ion-item>.
```